# Create table with inline create row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create table with inline create of row.

i.e. if you click on the button a row is created.

It will add new empty row (with two fields like in the code below) ,how should I do that?
I've tried with the following code without success,any idea how to do it?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(".createrow").hide();
});

$("#add").click(function () 
{
    $(".createrow").toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <h4>Role</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type='button' id='.createrow' class="btn ui-state-default medium"  style="width: 200px;">
            Create
            </button>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.checkBox1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.checkBox1)*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.checkBox1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure of what you're asking for but from what i can see perhaps something like the following will help?

Creating a new row in table based on button press.

working example:[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/xYsfR/)

**Jquery**

```
$('#addrow').click( function() {
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>');
});
```

**Example HTML**

```
<button id='addrow'>Add row</button>
<table id='table'>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>row</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Updated**
For row to appear at top of rows instead of before replace `append` with `prepend`
working example:[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/SQyer/)

Comment: Thanks this is similar to what I need ,voted up! How I make the row to start at the begining currently you have row and when you click you and new row after the row and so on ,how can I change that the new row will be always before the old one.Thanks!

Comment: do you mean first at the top of the rows?

Comment: I have added an example of `prepend` for rows to appear at top instead of end to the answer.

Comment: Thanks ,last question can you please give example where should I put the row fields of the table for example I have 5 column in the table and when I click on add I want to and new row with 5 editable fields how can i do that?

Comment: In the jquery where `<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>` is. You build the html in there with what you want to appear in each new row. Whatever is in there will appear in the new row.

Comment: Can you please provide simple example?

Comment: can you put an example of the thing you want to appear in the row please. and i shall show you with that.

Comment: for example Ive editable field in columan 1 and in column 2 check box...Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, heres the fiddle with checkboxes in their independent divs. http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/pc2bV/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? It adds a row for data input for a chart, maybe the script can be adapted for your table?

http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/live-editing-chart-data/

Comment: a link is hardly an answer